# Valid methods in being highlighted in red 'Unresolved Reference'

Tags: qt, go, jetbrains-ide, goland

How to solve this problem? The program works. But the methods in Gogland are highlighted in red. Qt version 5.8 is added.

```
Gogland (1.0 Preview) 1.0 EAP
Build #GO-171.4694.61, built on June 27, 2017
Gogland EAP User
Expiration date: September 25, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b21 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.8.0-58-generic


batis@dev:~$ printenv | grep GO
GOROOT=/usr/lib/go-1.8/
GOPATH=/home/batis/gocode/

package main

import (
    "os"
    "github.com/therecipe/qt/widgets"
)

func main() {
    widgets.NewQApplication(len(os.Args), os.Args)

    //create a window
    window := widgets.NewQMainWindow(nil, 0)

    ......

    widgets.QApplication_Exec()
}
```

[image: Some image]

[image: GOPATH]

[image: Some image]

[image: Test run OK!]

Comment: What does it have to do with `C++`?

Comment: The GOPATH seems to be incorrectly configured as well as the project seems to be in the wrong place. The project GOPATH should be removed and the project should be created under /home/batis/gocode/src/your/project/path. Then, make sure you have the dependency under /home/batis/gocode/src/github.com/therecipe/qt

Comment: @dlsniper Moved the project to /home/batis/gocode/src/batis/Qt. Problem still exists. Tell me please how you can check the dependencies.

Comment: project GOPATH deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The methods are defined in a big generated file that is not indexed by Gogland. To change the limit you should change [`idea.max.intellisense.filesize`](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties).

To do this, open custom properties file via `Help | Edit Custom Properties` menu and add something like this: `idea.max.intellisense.filesize=4500` for 4.5 MB limit. The size is in Kilobytes.

Please use carefully, indexing large files may influence index update speed dramatically.

Answer (score 37):

Ran into this recently with a project in 'bitbucket.org' GOPATH not finding ones in 'github.com'.  Checked the "Index entire GOPATH" box and it fixed it.

This option is present at: Files > Settings (Preferences) > Go > GOPATH

Comment: This sorted me out after updating to 2020.1.

Comment: The option is present at : 
Files > Settings (Preferences) > Go > GOPATH

Comment: This eventually worked for me though I had to restart Goland

Answer (score 3):

Possibly not valid for the original context, but the workaround I discovered is to rename the file where the method or other identifier is defined, allow Goland to reindex, and then rename it back to the original name.

Comment: what if this happens for 100 files?

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me after trying the other avenues. Restarting didn't even work.

Comment: I tried this, I renamed the file (first it asked me to confirm because the file was from outside the project), and it worked. Then I tried to rename it back to the original and the IDE wouldn't let me (wouldn't even show the confirmation prompt). But then the "undo" worked, even though it didn't show that it worked until I restarted. Very confusing, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

For me, none of the above solutions worked. Finally I could solve it by enabling "Enable Go Modules Integration" checkbox located under Preferences > Go > Go Modules.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

1. From the main menu, select File | Invalidate Caches.
2. In the Invalidate Caches dialogue, you can select additional actions that the IDE will perform while removing the cache files:
3. Clear file system cache and Local History
4. Click Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if `go.mod` is copied from another project without updating the project name:

```
// go.mod

module github.com/org/new-project

go 1.15
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was that I had GOPATH set to 1.15 but GOROOT set to 1.14, so you need to set them to the same version. You can find these settings in Preferences -> Go -> GOROOT or GOPATH.

I use gvm - Go Version Manager, that's why I have multiple Go versions in my system.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Goland 2021.1 on Windows 10 with go SDK 1.13. I solved the problem by installing the latest go version 1.16.3 side by side to version 1.13 that I need for my projects.
It turned out that my Windows 10 OS was patched with security updates that are not compliant with GoLand 2021.1 and SDK 1.13

Answer (score 0):

You need to "Enable Go Modules Integration" by going into "File" and selecting
settings and then "Go Modules"

[image]