# GoLand could not find reference: " Unresolved reference 'NewRGBA' "

Tags: go, goland

I am trying to do [this sample](https://tour.golang.org/methods/24), but GoLand could not find reference of NewRGBA function which is annoying, although it executes it correctly. I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921623/valid-methods-in-being-highlighted-in-red-unresolved-reference).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you accidentally marked the `image.go` file as plain text, which is why the IDE does not recognize anything defined in it correctly.

To fix this, go to `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` and search in the file types list for `Text`. There you should see the list of all files/extensions marked as plain text. Remove `image.go` from the list and see if this works correctly. Additionally, make sure that file file is not listed in the `Ignore files and folders` input, in the same section.

Comment: Thanks, after a few hours of searching this helped me!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for `gin.WrapH` function [utils.go](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/utils.go#:%7E:text=func%20WrapH(h%20http.Handler)%20HandlerFunc%20%7B). Tried the `Override File Type` option for utils.go in local module path which changed the file as a Go file but had a little cross sign where a tooltip marked that the file is excluded from compilation. The error `Unresolved reference` only went away when I selected the file, navigated to `File -> File Properties -> Associate with File Type -> Register new file type association`, and chose `Go files`

Answer (score 0):

restoring the IDE setting solved the problem for me. *I tried removing it from the text file association list but yet it wasn't solved*